# Golang Echo bind path param and json body separately

Tags: json, rest, go, web, go-echo

I am using Echo web framework in Golang and I wrote this code

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "net/http"
)

type ProjectPath struct {
    ID string `param:"id"`
}

type ProjectBody struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.POST("/project/:id", getProjectHandler)

    e.Start(":8080")
}

func getProjectHandler(c echo.Context) error {
    path := new(ProjectPath)
    if err := c.Bind(path); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    body := new(ProjectBody)
    if err := c.Bind(body); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Access the fields separately
    projectID := path.ID
    projectName := body.Name

    // Do something with the path and body fields...

    // Return a response
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Project ID: "+projectID+", Project Name: "+projectName)
}
```

I am trying to bind a path param and json body separately in a post request but I am getting an EOF error while trying to run it.

I am using replit for testing and the server is running on: `https://echotest.sandeepacharya.repl.co`

Curl Post Request:

```
 curl -X POST https://echotest.sandeepacharya.repl.co/project/123 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Sandeep"}'
```

Response:

```
{"message":"EOF"}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the binding separately then you'll need to use the *source specific* bind methods. These methods however are NOT available in the context, instead they are implemented by the [`DefaultBinder`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/labstack/echo/v4#DefaultBinder).

See also: https://echo.labstack.com/guide/binding/#direct-source

```golang
func getProjectHandler(c echo.Context) error {
    path := new(ProjectPath)
    if err := (&echo.DefaultBinder{}).BindPathParams(c, path); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    body := new(ProjectBody)
    if err := (&echo.DefaultBinder{}).BindBody(c, body); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Access the fields separately
    projectID := path.ID
    projectName := body.Name

    // Do something with the path and body fields...

    // Return a response
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Project ID: "+projectID+", Project Name: "+projectName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Bind() reads request body directly from the socket and once read it can't read again, hence the EOF error

https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/782#issuecomment-317503513

The issue is occured due to that you are attempted to bind the request body twice. The second `c.Bind()` will raise an error because the request body has already been read and consumed.

if you want to read the request with different struct, you can follow this approach

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type ProjectPath struct {
    ID string `param:"id"`
}

type ProjectBody struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type ProjectRequest struct {
    ProjectPath
    ProjectBody
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.POST("/project/:id", getProjectHandler)

    e.Start(":8080")
}

func getProjectHandler(c echo.Context) error {

    project := new(ProjectRequest)
    if err := c.Bind(project); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error happened due to::", err)
        return err
    }

    // Access the fields separately
    projectID := project.ID
    projectName := project.Name

    // Do something with the path and body fields...

    // Return a response
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Project ID: "+projectID+", Project Name: "+projectName)
}
```

or you can use only one struct to bind the request

```
type ProjectRequest struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    ID string `param:"id"`
}
```